# Переключение между темами DayNight

Tags: android

Как сделать возможность менять тему на Day/Night в настройках?

Answer (score 0):

Внутри Активити можно вызвать метод setTheme(), что-то вроде:

```
setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Wallpaper_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
```

Вызывать перед setContentView